# how to get all file names of remote server directory using HTTP url in java?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I want to access all file (name) via http URL.
Ex. http://app.examle.com/csv/
so i need to asses all the files (name) present in csv file

```
     headerBaseUrl="http://app.examle.com/csv/stock.csv";
    URL br = new URL(headerBaseUrl);
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(br.openStream()));
        // Create List for holding Employee objects
        List<BranchWiseStock> branchWiseStock = new ArrayList<BranchWiseStock>();

        String line = "";
        // Read to skip the header
        bufferedReader.readLine();
        // Reading from the second line
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] stockDetails = line.split(COMMA_DELIMITER);
            if (stockDetails.length > 0) {
                    System.out.println(" data "+stockDetails);
              }
            }
```

Here i can get data of 1 file easily 
but i want to read multiple files
Please help me...!

Comment: Please add what you have done so far

Comment: thanks alot  for replying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class FTPDownloadFileDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String hostname = "XXX";
        String username = "XXX";
        String password = "XXX";
        //Single file download
        //  String copyFrom = "serverFolderPath/";
        //  String copyTo = "localPath/";       
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = null;
        System.out.println("Trying to connect.....");
        try {
            session = jsch.getSession(username, hostname, 22);
            java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");

            session.setConfig(config);
            session.setPassword(password);
            session.connect(); 
            Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
            channel.connect();
            ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel; 

            sftpChannel.cd("serverFolderPath/csv/");
            Vector<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> list = sftpChannel.ls("*");
            for(ChannelSftp.LsEntry entry : list) {
                 System.out.println("Name :"+entry.getFilename()); 
            }
           //  sftpChannel.get(copyFrom, copyTo);
            sftpChannel.exit();
            session.disconnect();
        } catch (JSchException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  
        } catch (SftpException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Done !!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Use JSch Library and change into server configuration file change show listner

Comment: the Question is for http URL and not SSH